# Debian Squeeze: connect to A2DP (bluetooth) through command line

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth

I would like to turn my Lacie NAS into a A2DP bluetooth source, in order to stream audio to a bluetooth audio sink. The NAS runs Debian Squeeze in a chroot environment, and is connected to a Bluetooth dongle. I have no GUI installed on this NAS.

I can get bluetooth up with `hciconfig hci0 up`, and I can pair with the audio sink.

I created a file `~/.asoundrc` with the following contents:

```
pcm.btheadset {
    type bluetooth
    device C8:84:47:02:59:F4
    profile “auto”
}
```

Then I executed `hciconfig hci0 voice 0x0060`, which gave no output.

After that, I executed

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=btheadset
```

which gave the following error:

```
socket(): Address family not supported by protocol
Connection failure: Connection refused
```

Did I skip a step? Or is there anything else to accomplish what I want?

UPDATE: I think the underlying problem is that the required kernel modules are not loaded. I have currently the following modules running:

```
snd_page_alloc
soundcore 
btusb
uhci_hcd
rfcomm
l2cap
bluetooth
ftdi_sio 
usbserial
usblp 
ehci_hcd
loop
usb_storage
usbcore
```

Are there any other sound-specific kernel modules that I need to get sound over bluetooth working?

Comment: Is this Debian running in some sort of virtual machine in the NAS?